# Items not being added to multiple lists when saved in database.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following code on a controller in my MVC application:

```
        public void BulkUpdateGroupResident(List<TherapyGroup> therapyGroups)
        {
            foreach(var group in therapyGroups)
            {
                using (var context = new ResidentFirstDBContext())
                {
                    var currentGroup = context.TherapyGroups.Where(g => g.ID == group.ID).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (group == null)
                    {
                        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                    }
                    if (currentGroup.Residents == null)
                    {
                        currentGroup.Residents = new List<Resident>();
                    }
                    currentGroup.Residents.Clear();
                    foreach (var id in group.ResidentsId)
                    {
                        var resident = context.Residents.Where(r => r.ID.ToString() == id.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (resident == null)
                        {
                            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                        }
                        currentGroup.Residents.Add(resident);

                    }
                    context.Entry(currentGroup).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

            }

        }
```

The intended functionality is for it to fetch the therapy groups object (which is currently storing residentids and the groupid) from the Post to the controller, and then it should take those values and add the residents to the list of resident for the particular group; however, I have a problem because it seems the code will not push the residents into all of the correct groups when it is saved to the database. In fact, I have determined it only pushes them into the last selected group; however, this ONLY happens if the resident being added to two subsequent group is the same. For example, I want to add John to two different groups at the same time will not work. I know it's something to do with pushing the same object into different lists, but I am not sure how I go about fixing this problem. Any help is appreciated. Also, my Model code for the TherapyGroup Model is below. It may help you understand. Essentially, we are interested in the List on the model which is pointing to another object.

```
public class TherapyGroup
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public List<Resident> Residents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just as an aside you can, and should, replace `.Where(r => r.ID.ToString() == id.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();` with `.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ID.ToString() == id.ToString());` Plus, why are you comparing the Ids as strings and not integers?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code? Perhaps the problem is occurring in the way you are posting the therapygroups? Also, perhaps SingleOrDefault would be better since you should not get more than one match?

Comment: The IDs are stored as Guids. (Something we are moving away from where I work, but is currently still a thing.) Also, the Post Data is correct. I inserted a break point. I believe it's something to do with the data context only allowing a specific member "Resident" in the data context to be added to a list once. I can add different residents to different groups fine. I just can't add the same resident to all groups if that makes sense.

Comment: Why `currentGroup.Residents.Clear();`? Do you want to *replace* existing residents?

Comment: Right, this is a bulk update where while there could be residents that are already in the list, I go ahead and clear the list and push every resident back on versus having to check if there resident is there and add if not.

Comment: Looks like you should do `context.TherapyGroups.Include(g => d.Residents)`. You don't need the `null` check, nor is it necessary to set the group's state to `Modified`.

Comment: I would put on `else` on that call to `.Clear()` given what you know. I think it seems probably your database structure doesn't allow a resident to belong to more than one group - can you explain how the `List<Resident> Residents` maps to the DB?

Comment: That's where things are kind of fishy.. I can add residents to multiple groups, but I cannot do it to multiple groups at once.. As with this code. I am currently working on setting up a many to many relationship. I didn't think I would need that, but I am going to give it a go and see if it will work.

Comment: Hi @NetMage I can confirm that's what the problem is. Though I was pretty sure it was working fine in the traditional edit functionality now that I have crossed checked it I know it isn't. After looking in the database, I don't really see a table mapping the two. I will work on creating this.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I had a List<Resident> in my Therapy Group Model, but I needed to add a link to List<TherapyGroup> in my Resident model. Without that, it was only supporting a one to many relationship.